# Pyspark Class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not found even after including the jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to execute a simple select:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","TRUE") \
    .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive","TRUE") \
    .appName("sql_test") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db.table LIMIT 10").show()
```

on a table which is uses the org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe, but im getting the exception:

```
ERROR hive.log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not found
...
```

I have tried **every** suggestion I have found on stackoverflow and the cloudera forums, but nothing seems to change anything. The jar is included on the cluster and in addition I have tried:

- including the jar using --jars /path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- using .config("spark.jars","hdfs://path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar")
- using spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("hdfs://path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar")
- specifying the class using --class org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
- other configurations such as setting --conf spark.executor/driver.classpath.first=true, --conf spark.executor/driver.extraClassPath=hdfs://path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- deploying using client/cluster modes, setting master to local/yarn
- compiling the project in Scala instead of using Python

However **nothing** seems to work, the output is unchanged.
Using Hive I have no problem accessing the table, but I cannot seem to do anything using Spark.

Any suggestions what might be the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the jar like this in spark.sql? This is in addition to including the jar using --jars /path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark.sql(s"add jar /path/json-serde-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar")